# In SQL Server Mgmt Studio, why don't triggers automatically get updated when tables get renamed?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I ran into an issue last week where we renamed a bunch of tables in a SQL Server and it broke a bunch of triggers. I would have though SQL Server Mgmt Studio would have been smart enough to update those triggers but clearly not. Am I expecting too much? Is there a way to detect these issue where a trigger is referencing a table (or column as well) that no longer exists?

Comment: It's the same for Stored Procedures and views as well. SQL server DOES warm you that it will break anything referencing the old object name

Answer (score 7):

Trying the following in SSMS..

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T]
  (
     X INT
  );

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR]
ON [dbo].[T]
FOR INSERT
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM   [dbo].[T]
```

Then renaming the table as T2 and scripting out the trigger returns the following so I assume you are referring to the second table reference.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR]
ON [dbo].[T2]
FOR INSERT
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM   [dbo].[T]
```

If you use SQL Server Data Tools to manage your database schema instead of making schema changes directly in SSMS then this does have a rename refactoring. It isn't 100% comprehensive as you would still need to review for any possible usages in dynamic SQL or references to the table in external scripts but it would fix the issue above.

[image]